# My pump is streaming water out of valve from underneath pressure gauge

Tags: water, pump

I've drained the tank, refilled it & it's still a steady stream of water. Water pressure is good but pump kicks on as soon as you turn on a faucet & I know that's bad. I'm a single mom with no repair experience please help. Thanks, DB.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Can you send pics

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have lost the air charge on your pressure tank, if an old tank it may need replacing, 
try this it may give you some time , turn the pump off, use a bicycle pump to put air in the pressure tank there is usually a small valve like a car tire or bicycle has sticking out close to the top of the tank, fill to about 35 psi. You may have to open a faucet to get enough air in the tank but if the pump turns on at 40 35-38 psi air in the tank, if it turns on at 30 / 25-28psi in the tank will be needed. 
Now turn your pump and see if it is working normally, if the pump motor turns on and off rapidly more air is needed in the tank so you will need to turn off the pump let more water out and add air, a air compressor can be used if you have one but a bicycle hand pump will work it just takes a while, I have seen old diaphragm tanks last a couple of years longer by just adding air a few times. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If the leaky valve is fastened directly to the tank, then that may be leaking out the necessary air cushion inside the top portion and causing your problem. After the air leaks out, the water follows.

If that is the case, try draining the tank again; but before refilling it, shut off that valve. If that solves your issues, then the valve and pressure gauge should be replaced ASAP.

Also, note that pressure gauges themselves can fail and leak.

If water is actually coming from the valve, it may be possible to tighten the packing nut right behind the handle.